# Zlib installation error

Tags: software-installation

I'm trying to install Zlib for the first time and i'm rather new to linux in general. I'm running the commands in the files provided but i keep encountering this error
make: *** [Makefile:309: install-libs] Error 1
I don't understand what it means can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be compiling something from source. You may find this is unneccessary, as the thing you need may be already built and packaged in binary form.

`sudo apt install zlib1g`

If, however, you're building some other piece of software that requires zlib, then:

`sudo apt install zlib1g-dev`

Which will install the development headers required by your other software.

Comment: thanks that seemed to have fixed it